# Broken template went invisible

Tags: theme-development, themes

I made my wordpress run local and copied a new template
into the templates folder.
After logging in to the backend i got the message
that 
the **active theme** (the new one) **is broken** and
its reverting to default.

So far so good, it reverted to the default theme...
BUT the broken one doesn't even show up in the theme selection anymore!
How can i check what is broken or missing?... or at least make it visible again.

*(I alredy made shure that the index.php exists and i compiled the scss)*

Comment: Is your stylesheet (`style.css`) header correctly. What you are experiencing is normally due to a bad header in `style.css`. Post your stylesheet header

Comment: @PieterGoosen it actually was a missing * in the header. Didn't see it in the first place.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Enjoy ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be a WordPress Theme 
index.php and style.css are the basic requirement.
check Template Folder ( Whatever you name it ) and check index.php and style.css
in style.css you can see theme name and other details.

[WordPress Theme Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)

Comment: I got both, and neither of them is empty. To me it looks allright